# Reversing a string using recursion without <algorithm> or loops

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that reverses a string entirely without using the reverse() function or a loop (i.e. "hello" turns into "olleh") but I am getting a segmentation fault with the following code I drafted below:

```
void reverseString(string &s) {
    int strIndex = 0;
    int strSize = (s.size() - 1);

    if (s.size() <= 1) { 
        return;
    }

    else {
        if (strIndex < (s.size() / 2)) {
            int temp = s.at(strIndex);
            s.at(strIndex) = s.at(strSize);
            s.at(strSize) = temp;

            strIndex = strIndex + 1;
            strSize = strSize - 1;

            reverseString(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I am not allowed to change the parameter of the function.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Set a breakpoint, and step through your code, and watch your variables.

Comment: `strIndex` is `0`when you enter the function, so the `else` branch always does the same thing, so you're stuck in an infinite recursion, which causes a stack overflow. Study some more about how local variables work.

Comment: you need to pass strindex and strsize into reverseString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
strIndex = strIndex + 1;
```

can never have an effect, because local variables are not "reused" for the next invocation of the function. Each function call creates a new set of local variables.

Since you can not change the function signature, you'll have to change the string. Maybe something like:

```
void reverseString(string &s) {
    if(s.size() <= 1)
        return;
    char c = s[0];
    s = s.substr(1, s.size() - 1);
    reverseString(s);
    s += c;
}
```

Comment: Ahh. Never thought about using the substr function to alter my string. I knew I would have problems with the local variables if I were to call reverseString() again, but I wasn't sure on how to resolve it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You're just calling reverseString recursively on same string this will only lead to the same process repeating ad infinitum and lead to stackoverflow